Incorrectly rendered shadow for Canvas + cornerRadius in a Widget View
This code fails to render a regular blurry shadow in a Widget View, but works fine in a regular SwiftUI View:
Canvas { ctx, size in
    ctx.withCGContext { ctx in
        ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        ctx.addPath(UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height / 2.0)).cgPath)
        ctx.fillPath()
        
        ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
        ctx.addPath(UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: size.height / 2, width: size.width, height: size.height / 2)).cgPath)
        ctx.fillPath()
    }
}
.frame(width: 90, height: 60)
.cornerRadius(12)
.shadow(color: Color.red, radius: 12, x: 0, y: 2)


This seems to be caused by the .cornerRadius. Without it, it also works fine in the widget.
For rectangular content I found this workaround, but this fails for non-rectangular Canvas content:
.background(.background)
.cornerRadius(12)
.compositingGroup()

I suspect this is a SwiftUI bug and reported it to Apple (FB13771761).
Until then: Is there a reason why SwiftUI behaves like this when used for a Widget or is this indeed a bug? Is there a better workaround that also works for Canvas content that's not fully rectangular/opaque?
